# How to do Code Analysis for Python Inheritance?

Tags: python, code-analysis, static-analysis

I am searching for days to get the class hierarchy such as super and subclasses of any class (along with file path and line number, method over-rides references) something like code analysis of the project. The same functionality as PyCharm editor does. It will be a great help if someone can guide me on how to achieve this

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want some library/software? That’s specifically off-topic on StackOverflow. And anyway it sounds like PyCharm does that for you?

Comment: @barny I want some library to create vscode extension for this

Comment: Asking for libraries is *very specifically* off-topic on StackOverflow - that’s why I voted to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run a sort of code-analysis on Python, firstly you should remember Python is a **dynamically-typed** language, which means types are inferred.

In Python, everything is an `object`. Which means all your class definitions are also `objects`. You can use the [ast module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to parse any source file (`.py`) into an Abstract Syntax Tree. In this AST, you'll be able to see relationships between `names`. However, bear in mind that the ast module is **intraprocedural** , which means that if you want to build a complex interprocedural code analysis, you'll need some heavy working to do, specially when it comes to solving aliases problems, among countless other things. Then again, you'll never know the types of each `name` in the ast.

If you delve into this quest, you should extend the ast module to implement your own `NodeVisitor`, a class that will execute some routine in every node of your AST. Check more info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor)